# Infinite loading when lauching graphQL architect

Tags: neo4j, graphql, grandstack

I'm facing an infinite loading when I try to start graphQL architect from my Neo4J desktop app. I've found in the log than the app didn't found a file (grandstack.js).

```
[2020-09-10 10:05:38.615] [info] Executing node graphql inferschema --neo4j-user neo4j --neo4j-uri bolt://localhost:7687 --neo4j-password MYPASSWORD  --database neo4j
[2020-09-10 10:05:38.626] [error] Process [undefined] error {
  constructor: 'Error',
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn node',
  path: 'node',
  spawnargs: [
    'C:\\Users\\MYUSERNAME\\.Neo4jDesktop\\graphApps\\grandstack\\graphql-architect\\dist\\node_modules\\grandstack\\dist\\grandstack.js',
    'graphql',
    'inferschema',
    '--neo4j-user',
    'neo4j',
    '--neo4j-uri',
    'bolt://localhost:7687',
    '--neo4j-password',
    'vy701y46v9',
    '',
    '--database',
    'neo4j'
  ],
  stack: 'Error: spawn node ENOENT\n' +
    '    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:264:19)\n' +
    '    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)\n' +
    '    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)'
}
```

I don't understand why I'm facing this error because the file exist.

I'm using the v1.3.4 Neo4J Desktop app and my database is running in v3.5.21

Here's the screen of the loading : [Infinite loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rao0Y.png)

I also cannot launch the GraphQL server (when I click the Start button, the message "INFO :: Local Graph Process Exit" appear and nothing else occur).

I've also an other computer where I use the graphQL architect app with the exact same version and everything work well.

Comment: Thanks for posting this, Nathan. I am running into the same problem using Neo4j Desktop v1.3.3, Neo4j 3.5.17, macOS 10.15.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it is the same issue but I ran into a problem where Neo4j Desktop GraphQL Architect Local GraphQL server would not load.  After installing the latest version npm/node.js, it started to work.

Comment: I have the same issue. I tried the update to npm - which was much needed. However, the issue persists. There's not much to go on from the initial screens. Will research.